# Partial date in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, ruby-on-rails-4, type-conversion

I have a `date type` column in my table which is taken input from a form using `f.input`. But, I want only the month and year to be taken from the form. Is there any way that I can hide the `day` dropdown or is there any other data type which can take care of this?

Comment: So you want to save a `date` to a DB _without_ the `day`?

Comment: I'll set the default day to be the 1st in db but don't want the day to be shown on the front end.

Comment: you can use `:discard_day => true` in your `date_select`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/date_select):

> `:discard_day` - Set to true if you don’t want to show a day select. This includes the day as a hidden field instead of showing a select field. Also note that this implicitly sets the day to be the first of the given month in order to not create invalid dates like 31 February.

Example from the docs:

```
date_select("article", "written_on", start_year: 1995, use_month_numbers: true, discard_day: true, include_blank: true)
```